# What is the difference between MathJax and React-mathjax?

Tags: reactjs, mathjax

I am doing a React project and there are math notations need to be rendered. I found this react package called [react-mathjax](https://github.com/SamyPesse/react-mathjax). But my supervisor insists [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) is the only solution which enables full semantics (put your mouse over math notation, and a little window appears which tells us what it means).

I am wondering what is the difference between these two packages? Is react-mathjax essentially a package that wraps MathJax into a react component? After all, using a react component in react project is very easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the package is a wrapper for MathJax which makes it easier to use in React apps. In the end, it's the same code from MathJax that renders your math equations and notations. You can see in [src/Provider.js](https://github.com/SamyPesse/react-mathjax/blob/master/src/Provider.js) that they load the MathJax script.

You could add MathJax yourself to the React app or use this package if it fits your needs.